# I want to animate view on setVisibility but it works only for the first time

Tags: android, animation, visibility

I've added

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

to my recycler view and visibility is handle in `onClick` as follow, but it works only at first click.

```
rlOtherOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            if (rvModeCheck.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                rvModeCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                rvModeCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

what should I do?

Comment: Which animation you are looking for ? Like Alpha, rotate, ..

Comment: Which animation you are looking

Comment: post full activity code

Comment: i want to animate parent layout expanding below slowly and recyclerView appearing. recycler view is added in relative layout. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Please add like above to your root layout of your XML...

Answer (score 1):

Try animate via code instead

```
rlOtherOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            if (rvModeCheck.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                rvModeCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rvModeCheck.setAlpha(0);
                rvModeCheck.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(300).setListener(null);

            } else {
                rvModeCheck.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        rvModeCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code within an onCreateView method if it's not already.

May need to add some more information/code to your question to get better help.